# Jquery Dropdown menu mouseenter delay

Tags: javascript, jquery

so i have a dropdown menu with jquery that utilizes the slide down and up functions.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#menu>li').mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).find('ul>li').slideDown(250);
        $(this).find('ul>li').css('position', 'relative');
        $(this).find('ul>li').css('z-index', 9999);
    });
    $('#menu>li').mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).find('ul>li').slideUp(250);
        $(this).find('ul>li').css('position', 'relative');
        $(this).find('ul>li').css('z-index', 9999);
    });
});
```

How can i make it that my after my mouseleave function executes there is a delay before the mouseenter function can register again?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Create a `dropDownDisabled` variable that defaults to false. In your mouse leave handler set the variable to true, and use `setTimeout()` to change it back to false after x milliseconds. In your mouse enter handler test the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a variable with initial timeout as 0 and once it goes in `mouseleave` function update it to value you want to delay.

**EDIT**
Use `clearTimeout` to clear previously created timeout.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var delay=0;
    var timeout;
    $('#menu>li').mouseenter(function(){
      timeout= setTimeout(function(){
        $(this).find('ul>li').slideDown(250);
        $(this).find('ul>li').css('position', 'relative');
        $(this).find('ul>li').css('z-index', 9999);
      },delay);
    });
    $('#menu>li').mouseleave(function(){
        if(typeof timeout!=='undefined'){
          clearTimeout(timeout);
        }
        delay=250;
        $(this).find('ul>li').slideUp(250);
        $(this).find('ul>li').css('position', 'relative');
        $(this).find('ul>li').css('z-index', 9999);
    });
});
```